# Script to enable bitlocker in All Drive

Tags: powershell, vbscript, bitlocker

I am trying to enable bitlocker in all domain joined user machines in my office.

I have used a Widows task scheduler script to enable bitlocker in all machines.

But the below code is enabling bitlocker in C drive alone.

I need to enable this in all drive in the laptop. How do i proceed. I have attached the script below

```
$TPM = Get-WmiObject win32_tpm -Namespace root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm | where {$_.IsEnabled().Isenabled -eq 'True'} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$WindowsVer = Get-WmiObject -Query 'select * from Win32_OperatingSystem where (Version like "6.2%" or Version like "6.3%" or Version like "10.0%") and ProductType = "1"' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
$BitLockerReadyDrive = Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue


#If all of the above prequisites are met, then create the key protectors, then enable BitLocker and backup the Recovery key to AD.
if ($WindowsVer -and $TPM -and $BitLockerReadyDrive) {

#Creating the recovery key
Start-Process 'manage-bde.exe' -ArgumentList " -protectors -add $env:SystemDrive -recoverypassword" -Verb runas -Wait

#Adding TPM key
Start-Process 'manage-bde.exe' -ArgumentList " -protectors -add $env:SystemDrive  -tpm" -Verb runas -Wait
sleep -Seconds 15 #This is to give sufficient time for the protectors to fully take effect.

#Enabling Encryption
Start-Process 'manage-bde.exe' -ArgumentList " -on $env:SystemDrive -em aes256" -Verb runas -Wait

#Getting Recovery Key GUID
$RecoveryKeyGUID = (Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint $env:SystemDrive).keyprotector | where {$_.Keyprotectortype -eq 'RecoveryPassword'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty KeyProtectorID

#Backing up the Recovery to AD.
manage-bde.exe  -protectors $env:SystemDrive -adbackup -id $RecoveryKeyGUID

#Restarting the computer, to begin the encryption process
Restart-Computer}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [powershell script to run bitlocker](https://serverfault.com/questions/916060/powershell-script-to-run-bitlocker)

Comment: yes..no one provided resolution for that....can you guys provide solution for above question?

Comment: If you don't get an answer, don't duplicate your question. This is not a script writing service. Apparently you need to replace `$env:SystemDrive` with other drives and iterate. But we'd all use GP, instead, as already mentioned on the comments of your other question.

Comment: Hi Jokinen,  Thanks for your reply. I have used this link to setup this https://adameyob.com/2016/12/08/zero-touch-bitlocker-deployments/  how can i do this for other drives too. is it possible to do this without script?

Comment: from above answer where do i add iterate for the drives please?

Comment: Just leave out the `-MountPoint` and iterate through all your returned objects. I would use a `for` loop instead of `if` in this case.

Comment: You don't need to make it difficult using a script you can use a group policy https://specopssoft.com/blog/group-policy-configure-bitlocker/

Answer (score 0):

You could try this code to get all drives, then run the bitlocker cmdlets inside the "Foreach"

```
$drives = Get-Volume | Where {$_.DriveType -like "Fixed" -and $_.DriveLetter -ne $null -and $_.FileSystem -ne $null}
Foreach ($drive in $drives){
    $drive.DriveLetter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a Group Policy much easier

https://specopssoft.com/blog/group-policy-configure-bitlocker/